# rails redirect_to url not working, returns: filter chain halted as :redirect_to_https rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, destroy

Stumped here, on our website we have an FAQ, on the admin side we have the ability to add/edit/delete FAQ categories and individual FAQ's inside those categories.

In my faq_controller I have these 2 methods:

```
def destroy
  faq = load_faq_for_faq_category
  faq.destroy if faq
  redirect_to "/faq_categories/#{params[:faq_category_id]}"
end

private

def load_faq_for_faq_category
  faq = Faq.where(:id => params[:id]).first!

  if faq.faq_category_id != params[:faq_category_id].to_i
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "FAQ doesn't belong to specified FAQ Category"
  end
  faq
end
```

This line:

```
redirect_to "/faq_categories/#{params[:faq_category_id]}"
```

Used to be:

```
redirect_to :back
```

but that wasn't working to I switched to the more explicit path but no matter what I do it won't destroy the faq.

My server log says this:

```
Started DELETE "/faq_categories/4/faq/50" at 2012-12-19 15:44:32 +0000
Processing by FaqController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"faq_category_id"=>"4", "id"=>"50"}
Redirected to http://my_staging_server/faq_categories/4/faq/50
Filter chain halted as :redirect_to_https rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The weirdest thing about this though is that it works on my local machine. My local log looks like this:

```
Started DELETE "/faq_categories/1/faq/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-19 09:03:05 -0700
Processing by FaqController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"faq_category_id"=>"1", "id"=>"5"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Role Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 1 AND `roles`.`lookup_code` = 'root' LIMIT 1
Faq Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `faqs`.* FROM `faqs` WHERE `faqs`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `faqs`.* FROM `faqs` WHERE `faqs`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `faqs` WHERE `faqs`.`id` = 5
SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `faqs` SET position = (position - 1) WHERE (`faq_category_id` = 1 AND position > 1)
(45.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/faq_categories/1
Completed 302 Found in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 46.3ms)
```

Which is correct so...

**TL:DR** Why is this `redirect_to` not working on my staging server, and what exactly does the `filter chain halted as :redirect_to_https` line mean?

Comment: Does the rails application located at `http://[domain_name]/[alias]/` in your production server?

Comment: @code4j does it do what at that location?

Comment: it is really a matter of whether the `root` of server equal to the `root` of your application or not. Can you go to `http://my_staging_server/faq_categories/4/faq/50` by just copying this link into browser?

Comment: @code4j yes, I have to be logged in, only admins can edit faq items, but if I'm logged in I can go directly there by copying that.

Comment: I think `redirect_to` is working. After you go to that path, there is a filter called `:redirect_to_https` in filters chain to stop it. (in order word, halted)

Comment: @code4j alright then, but why is the filter being called? and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have left a answer :) Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you set **HTTPS** in your production config file but not development config file.

Say your controller is called **faq_categories**, and the method is called **show**

You can do it by:

```
class faq_categories_Controller
    skip_filter :redirect_to_https
end
```

which will prevent the HTTPS checking

**Or you can do it by:**

```
redirect_to {:protocol => 'https://', :controller => 'faq_categories', :action => 'show'}
```

Comment: oo I made a mistake in my answer ,haha 
should be `skip_filter `

Answer (score 0):

The site was already using https, so I still don't know why the filter chain was breaking but @code4j started me in the right direction.

Adding this to my faq_controller fixed the problem:

```
skip_filter :redirect_to_https
```